# Strange behaviour of Stack Exchange websites

Tags: bug

The webiste of Stack Overflow (and all its subsites, even this meta.stackexchange website too) always has a drop down box open, and also the shape of website is quite out of the layout.

At first I thought, it may be because of a slow Internet connection, but I am using a 4 Mbit/s broadband connection. Further, I am seeing on both my Windows and Linux systems. I have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, but I am seeing the same results. A screenshot is attached which is also appearing too large on my screen:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow website]

Comment: Something on your side is blocking the required JS/CSS files... open dev console (F12) go to Network tab and you'll see. To bypass this block, if it's caused by some funky security software, go to the secure site e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/`. (can't post as link because the comment will strip the https away.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: Cheers, so it's the same as a recent report of this kind. :)