# With multiple gold tag badges, what determines which of them will be used as hammer?

Tags: support, dupehammer

I have gold tag badges for both [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) here on Meta Stack Exchange. When voting to close a question tagged with both as a duplicate, only one of those is selected as the hammer:

> [image]

At first I thought tag popularity (number of questions asked with that tag) determines the tag to be used, but today I got a counter example on Stack Overflow: (Where I have gold badges for both [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [html](/questions/tagged/html), with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) being more popular.)

> [image]

So, what determines which tag is being used as a hammer?

Comment: First alphabetically?

Comment: @Cai hmm.. interesting theory!

Comment: Already asked on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320062/dupe-hammer-multiple-tags-multiple-gold-badges) (no answers). It was also one of the things asked [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268278/323179) (but no relevant, satisfying answers IMO).

Answer (score 20):

Sorry to be the bearer of boring news, but we do not sort the tag badges you've acquired in any particular way. We just fetch a list of them, intersect that list with the tags on the question, and remove any tags that the user participated in adding to the question. It then just takes the first one in the list, whatever that might be.

While that means the behavior of which tag badge gets selected is inherently undefined, it should be loosely based on the order that the tag badge itself was first created and inserted into the database (we don't keep all three classes of every tag badge for every tag in the database - they just get inserted once someone first earns them).

Here on Meta, that looks like this:

[image: List of gold tag badges on Meta Stack Exchange]

That the required tags mostly happened to be created in alphabetical order was just coincidence that gave the resemblance of being sorted. But because each site is different, this ordering would be different on every site where the dupe-hammer is being used.

Comment: Does this mean the order is loosely based on the order the *tags* formed or the actual golden badges?

Comment: @Exempt-Medic It is not based on when the tags were created, but the tag badges themselves. Those are not created until the first person is eligible for the tag badge. Of note: the Badges table does not actually have a CreationDate column, so it's not technically based on date at all but just the order they were inserted into the table.

Answer (score 5):

I have nothing official to back this up, only a bit of searching for dupe-hammer closed questions here on MSE, but it looks like it chooses the first tag alphabetically.

Here is a reasonably sized sample of questions (all the questions I checked, I found none contradicting my theory) here on MSE that were closed by a dupe-hammer from a user (mostly you) with more than one gold tag badge for the closed question's tags; all were closed with the tag that comes first alphabetically:

- [Why is an accepted answer not counted in the Score of a Next tag badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290135/307988)
- [Do questions disassociated from an account count towards a question ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281136/307988)
- [Where did the Programmers Stack Exchange site go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289901/307988)
- [Is it possible to close questions because they are already solved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288984/307988)
- [Stack Exchange name pun?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287973/307988)
- [Strange behaviour of Stack Exchange websites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284352/307988)
- [Why wasn't I ever informed that that a bounty was put on my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284054/307988)
- [Tag links not hidden by spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290275/307988)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290240/307988
- [Should Badges that can no longer be awarded be removed from the 'Badges' panel?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289702/307988)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289561/307988
- [Searching question problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290091/307988)
- [How to vote to reopen a question from the iOS app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286376/307988)

Comment: Makes sense, hopefully a dev will come by and just confirm. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 [Had this come up at rpg](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11784/62294), and it seems alphabetically is not the rule, the question had [dnd-5e] and [spells] and my hammer picked [spells].

Comment: @ThomasMarkov well, just hammered [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370976/click-does-not-work-for-stack-exchange-pages?noredirect=1) and even though [tag:support] has more questions than [tag:bug], it chose "bug" hammer. So weird.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov hmm..... maybe it picks the last earned hammer? When did you earn your [spells] hammer on RPG? Before or after the [dnd-5e] hammer? ([tag:bug] hammer is my most recent)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 I earned [dnd-5e] first.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the [dnd-5e] tag was added to the question only later, originally it had only [spells] so maybe when choosing hammer it looks first in the original set of tags?